# How to delete an image when I delete the path in mysql db with PDO

Tags: jquery, mysql, file-io, pdo

I need to know how can I delete the $imagenes form the path in my db...I can't do it successfully(in the db is successfully deleted)...I already put the unlink code but in error log show me the id of the image but not the name of the image...here is my PHP code:

**---EDITED---**

so I don't know how make it to delete the $imagenes in that id(idToDelete)...can I SELECT the table before or later?? or is not necessary

**here is the table**

---

- id_imagen (int PK)
- imagenes (varchar 100)
- id_paciente (int FK)
- f_imagen (current_timestamp)

---

in ***personal.php*** I have the image and with ajax call I try to delete it:

```
/*the styles of del button and wrapper */
<style type="text/css">
.del_wrapper{float:right;}
.content_wrapper {
max-width: 100%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
</style>
/*the ajax call */
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#gallery .del_button", function(e)
    {
    e.returnValue = false;
    var clickedID = this.id.split('-');
    var DbNumberID = clickedID[1];
    var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID;
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "delimage.php?ts=" + new Date().getTime(),
dataType:"text",
data:myData,
success:function(response){
$('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut("slow");
},
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
alert(thrownError);
}
});
});
});
</script>

/*the image gallery */
<div id="gallery">
<?
$sql = $conn->prepare("select * from IMAGENES where id_paciente = $_GET[id_paciente] order by id_imagen ASC");
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$id_imagen = $row['id_imagen'];
$imagenes = $row['imagenes'];
echo "<div class='del_wrapper' id='item_".$row['id_imagen']."'><a href='#' class='del_button' id='del-".$row['id_imagen']."'>";
echo "<img src='../images/icon_del.gif' border='0' />";
echo "</a>";
echo "<a href='../$imagenes' class='group4'>";
echo "<img src='../$imagenes' class='image_thumbnail'  />";
echo "</a> </div>";
}
?></div>
```

**and the code in *delimage.php* with the select:**

```
<?
include_once("config.php");
if(isset($_POST["recordToDelete"]) && strlen($_POST["recordToDelete"])>0 && is_numeric($_POST["recordToDelete"]))
{
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT id_imagen,imagenes FROM IMAGENES where id_imagen = $_GET[id_imagen]");
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$recordToDelete=$data['imagenes'];
unlink("../imagenes/$imagenes");
}
    $idToDelete = filter_var($_POST["recordToDelete"],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if($stmt=$conn->prepare("delete from IMAGENES WHERE id_imagen=$idToDelete"))
    $stmt->bindParam("$idToDelete",$id_imagen,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
       $dbh = null;
}
?>
```

the ajax call works because in fiddler I see the id of the image that will delete it in delimage.php  but only delete the path in db and not the image inside of imagenes folder

Comment: You can't mix $POST[] and $GET[].What you use depends on FORM method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: use [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) in the following way:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `IMAGENES` WHERE `id_imagen` = :idToDelete")
$sth->bindParam(':idToDelete', $id_imagen, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

But before that most probably you have to use SELECT in order to get the name of the file. After that use that name in unlink, not the variable with ID. Post your table structure here if you want good advice.

Quite not sure what is $_POST["recordToDelete"] and why you trying to use $_GET after that.
If the `imagenes` column store file names you want to delete, based on `id_imagen` try the following way:

```
<?
include_once("config.php"); 
/*hope above is the connection with MySQL and that connection is $conn */

if(isset($_POST["recordToDelete"]) && strlen($_POST["recordToDelete"])>0 && is_numeric($_POST["recordToDelete"])) {
  $idToDelete = filter_var($_POST["recordToDelete"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  /* following will give you file name on the corresponding id from table */
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `imagenes` FROM IMAGENES where `id_imagen` = :id_imagen"); 
  $stmt->bindParam(':id_imagen', $id_imagen, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  if ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
    /* this will delete the file */
    unlink("../imagenes/" . $result[0]);
    /* and here you will delete the record in DB if this is your intention also */
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM IMAGENES WHERE id_imagen = :idToDelete"))
    $stmt->bindParam(":idToDelete", $id_imagen, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
  }
}
$conn = null;    //Disconnect
?>
```

First, try to understant every row, second - make backup of your DB, after that - try carefully with sampple data.

Comment: I already edit the question and put table structure..but can't get the id with select

Comment: I tried your code but not work..not give me any error in error log file.. thank you for your support!

Comment: hi my friend, well I just change a little bit you code and works very good!! thank you for your support   Best Regards   _I just change the :idToDelete to $idToDelete in select and then in delete and that make the magic!!_